# expanding/resizing user created graphic with php

Tags: php

I am trying to display data on a php created graphic on-the-fly; the data is in the form of bars, but the problem is that I have to specify the size of the graphic in advance using imagecreate(550, 450); but I need to be able to alter the width of the graphic as I don't know in advance how many columns I will need to display until after the imagecreate function is called. Is there a way to resize such a graphic?

Comment: Do you have any code? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I do, but its a little complicated, so I thought I'd ask a generic question about it.

Comment: If you post even a snippet of your code to explain what you're trying to get resolved, you're more likely to get proper assistance for your issue. You can remove the fluff of the program (make an *example* program with just the basics of what you are trying to accomplish). This shows people that you've *tried* something and helps us to determine possible resolutions for your problem.